# How to convert JsonArray to ArrayList but JsonObject In JsonArray is not the same structure

Tags: android, json

How can I convert below `JsonArray` with different `JsonObject's` into Single `Arraylist`

```
[{
    "type": "textCard",
    "data": {
        "dataType": "TextCard",
        "id": 0,
        "type": "header5",
        "text": "",
        "subTitle": null,
        "actionUrl": null,
        "adTrack": null,
        "follow": null
    },
    "tag": null,
    "id": 0,
    "adIndex": -1
},
{
    "type": "briefCard",
    "data": {
        "dataType": "BriefCard",
        "id": 30,
        "icon": "*jpeg",
        "iconType": "square",
        "title": "#",
        "subTitle": null,
        "description": "",
        "actionUrl": "B8%B8%E6%88%8F",
        "adTrack": null,
        "follow": {
            "itemType": "category",
            "itemId": 30,
            "followed": false
        },
        "ifPgc": false
    },
    "tag": null,
    "id": 0,
    "adIndex": -1
}]
```

Comment: If you want help, you need to clean up your post. Edit and put your JSON in a codeblock then take a minute an better explain your situation and problem. Right now, your post is very unclear on what your issue is and what you are stuck on.

Comment: you use key "dataType" to parse many different object.

Comment: @codeMagic  thank you ! is my first time ,but i don't think you get my point

Answer (score 0):

try this ,

```
 try {
                JSONArray array=new JSONArray(res);
                if (array.length()>0){
                    for (int i=0;i<array.length();i++){
                        JSONObject object1=array.getJSONObject(i);

                        JSONObject object2=object1.getJSONObject("data");

                        // do this for your needed objects

                        if (object2.has("icon")){
                            Log.d("icon",object2.getString("icon"));
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

[image]

Comment: I don't think it's a good solution.   In fact ，jsonArray has 100+ elements,each element has many var

Comment: Json array has 100+ elements it's not a problem because for loop has done this. inside array elements you need to check variables,otherwise you con't do.variables are changing each array elements , problem occur api only